# Problema mostrando grid

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Buenas estoy tratando de dar formato a una respuesta agregando para ello un flip, quiero mostrar las columnas una al lado de la otra, y esto me lo hace sin problemas cuando muestro solo la imagen, pero cuando le agrego elementos adicionales deja de funcionar. Aqui el codigo:

/css/

```
         /*------------------------------------
                IMG AREA
          ----------------------------------*/
          .imgs div  {
           display: inline; 
          }
```

java

```
          for (var i = 0; i <= (totalSupply-1); i++) {
               getitemDetails(i).then(function(response){
                $("#mygrid").append(`<div class="imgs">
               <a href="item/${i}">
               <img width="250px" height="250px" class="toknImg" src="api/img/${response.name}"></a>   
               </div>`);
           });
          }
```

Esto es lo que muestra

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si le agrego algo adicional como una nota debajo

Ejemplo

```
          for (var i = 0; i <= (totalSupply-1); i++) {
               getitemDetails(i).then(function(response){
                $("#mygrid").append(`<div class="imgs">
               <a href="item/${i}">
               <img width="250px" height="250px" class="toknImg" src="api/img/${response.name}"><br>${i}</a>   
               </div>`);
           });
          }
```

me lo muestra así

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y tengo este codigo que me hace el flip de la imagen pero muestra las imagenes como la segunda muestra, ya no se que hacer

```
    /* entire container, keeps perspective */
       .flip-container {
         perspective: 1000px;
       }
    /* flip the pane when hovered */
         .flip-container:hover .flipper, .flip-container.hover .flipper {
           transform: rotateY(180deg);
         }           

       .flip-container, .front, .back {
         width: 300px;
         height: 300px;
       }

       /* flip speed goes here */
       .flipper {
         transition: 0.6s;
         transform-style: preserve-3d;
         position: relative;
       }

       /* hide back of pane during swap */
       .front, .back {
         backface-visibility: hidden;
         position: absolute;
         top: 0;
         left: 0;
       }

       /* front pane, placed above back */
       .front {
         z-index: 2;
       /* for firefox 31 */
         transform: rotateY(0deg);
       }

       /* back, initially hidden pane */
       .back {
         transform: rotateY(180deg);
       }
```

deseo integrar este codigo de flip con el for que me muestra la data. De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Estas confundiendo fuertemente a java y javascript, amigo, no estas usando java, el lenguaje que estas usando se llama javascript, lo cual NO es lo mismo, espero no tengas que toparte con java algun dia... es super complicado :c

Comment: Ciertamente un error de mi parte, gracias por la corrección, estoy usando javascript en html, esto lo tengo en un html y no encuentro la forma de ordenarlo apropiadamente